# Installing gems inside (J)Ruby code

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

I am using **JRuby** along with **Cucumber** and is looking for a way of running

```
 jruby -S gem update --system
 jruby -S gem install cucumber
```

from within the Java [ScriptEngine](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html). No amount of Googling have let me to a solution to this problem. Basically I want to be able to do something like this

```
 ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
 ScriptEngine jRubyEngine = manager.getEngineByName("jruby");
 : // some unknown code here
 jRubeEngine.eval("call gems install/update from inside JRuby")
```

Is there a way of accomplishing this?

Comment: In case anyone stumbles across this question, I recently created a screen cast here that might help: http://javajing.com/2012/06/01/ruby-from-java.html. I believe jruby-complete comes with a version of the gem command that you can make use of from java. For example, you can install the sass gem like so: `java -jar jruby-complete-1.6.7.jar -S gem install -i ./sass-gems sass --no-rdoc --no-ri`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RubyGems is just a Ruby library. The `gem` command is only a thin wrapper around the library. Everything you can do with the command, you can do with the library.

I've never actually used the library, but I guess what you want to look at is the [Gem::DepencyInstaller](http://RubyGems.RubyForge.Org/rubygems-update/Gem/DependencyInstaller.html) and the code would look something like this (*completely* untested, just pulled out of my you-know-what):

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine jRubyEngine = manager.getEngineByName("jruby");
String s = "
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'rubygems/dependency_installer'
  Gem::DependencyInstaller.new.install('cucumber')
";
jRubyEngine.eval(s);
```